# How to remove remote origin/refs/heads/master

Tags: git, remote-branch

Don't ask me how but I managed to get accidentally the following remote branches in a git repository:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/refs/heads/master
```

All are pointing to the same commit. How can I remove the unnecessary listing for  `origin/refs/heads/master`?

I tried to do the following

```
$ git push origin :refs/heads/master
error: dst refspec refs/heads/master matches more than one.
```

But as shown, this gives an error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution was to delete the branch `refs/heads/refs/heads/master`

```
git push origin :refs/heads/refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 45):

That's not actually a branch on the remote - it's just a local ref that claims to be representing something on the remote, just as origin/master represents the master branch on the remote. The full name of the ref is `refs/remotes/origin/refs/heads/master`. All you have to do to delete it is:

```
git branch -r -d origin/refs/heads/master
```

It's vaguely possible that you managed to push this as well (but you'd have had to try extra hard to do so). If you did, I'd simply listing the refs of origin:

```
git ls-remote origin
```

and then, if there's anything stupid there, using `git push origin :<refname>` to get rid of it.

P.S. If this doesn't do it for you, you're going to want to use `git for-each-ref` to see all of your refs, and possibly `git ls-remote origin` to see all the remote ones, and track down *exactly* which things don't belong, with their fully qualified refnames.

Comment: Hmm, it was origin/refs/heads/refs/heads/master and I deleted it with `git push origin :refs/heads/refs/heads/master`

Comment: @Peter: well, that is what I guessed in the first paragraph. I'm impressed that you managed to get it into the remote; it took me a bit to figure out how to do that myself! Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 5):

It's

```
git branch -r -d origin/ref/heads/master
```

instead of

```
git branch -r -d origin/refs/heads/master
```

in the code part to delete branch. There is difference in ref word in the code.