# Remove refs/remotes entirely

Tags: git, git-remote

When I do `git ls-remote` to my remote repository it shows:

```
HEAD
refs/heads/BranchA
refs/heads/master
refs/remotes/origin/BranchA
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

How can I delete the last two entries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890772/how-to-remove-remote-origin-refs-heads-master http://superuser.com/questions/283309/how-to-delete-the-git-reference-refs-original-refs-heads-master

Comment: Not just a duplicate, but Google for "git delete remote branch" seems to yield lots of results, too.

Comment: I fear the first ones will deleted...these post doesn't answer that

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by pushing an empty ref, so:

```
git push origin :BranchA :master
```

will do the trick.  If you follow that with a 'git fetch --prune origin', then they won't show up in 'git branch -a' either.

Comment: How would it guarantee the first two ones will not be deleted.?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer I found on SO itself and it worked like a charm.

git push repository :refs/remotes/origin/BranchA

git push repository :refs/remotes/origin/master